# Angular: Template rerenders Array while its length does not change

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, javascript-objects, angular2-changedetection

Here is a parent component's template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let set of timeSet; index as i">
    <time-shift-input *ngIf="enabled"
        [ngClass]="{ 
            'mini-times' : miniTimes, 
            'field field-last': !miniTimes,
            'field-central': !canAddSet,
            'field-central--long': (canAddSet || canDeleteSet) && !miniTimes }"
        [startHour]="set.startHour" 
        [endHour]="set.endHour"
        [endsNextDay]="set.endsNextDay" 
        [canAddSet]="canAddSet()"
        [canDeleteSet]="canDeleteSet(i)"
        [required]="true"
        (onAddSet)="onAddSet(i)"
        (onDeleteSet)="onDeleteSet(i)"
        (onChange)="onShiftTimes($event, i)"></time-shift-input>
</ng-container>
```

Here is the code which will update the `timeSet` array after `onChange` event has been triggered:

```
public onShiftTimes( set: TimeSchedule | Array<TimeSchedule>, ind?: number ): void {
    if ( ind !== undefined ) {
        this.timeSet[ind] = <TimeSchedule>set;
    } else {
        this.timeSet = <Array<TimeSchedule>>set;
    }
    this.timeChanged.emit({
        data: this.timeSet,
        di: this.dayIndex
    });
}
```

The child component, `<time-shift-input>` is getting re-rendered every time the `onShiftTimes` method has been called, EVEN when the the length of the array stays the same.

Which is a bummer, because it breaks user experience in an annoying way (removes focus, etc). I thought that pushing OR updating an index of an existing array won't change the object reference for the array, so the `ngFor` loop will not be triggered. However `ngOnInit` in `<time-shift-input>` is getting called every time after `onShiftTimes`...

Any ideas how to prevent re-rendering?

Answer (score 1):

RTFM, as they say.

`trackByFn` to the rescue - that was the simple and correct solution to my problem. More on this gem:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#ngForTrackBy
https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-4-ngfor-example#trackBy